# Flow&Dynamic TextView with images inside it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-custom-view

I think that HTML might be a solution. But how can I achieve this:

[image]
[image]

with multiple screens sizes support?

I have found this library: [FlowTextView](https://github.com/deano2390/flowtextview)
But it doesn't provide the way to put images **inside** text, like html does. And I also want to drag/resize image's inside text :D

Important to keep images on the same place on multipile devices.

So. What is the solution? Must I go ahead with custom View?

**What can you recomend?**

Comment: What do you mean images inside text? Why do you need images inside text? From the picture above that library should work.

Comment: @cyroxis Look at the second picture. Why? Because it's the future of my diary application :) I want also to have the ability to drag image through lines of text. This library is keeping images not like in-line tags(`text text text<image src="cat.png"> text text`), but as ImageView inside FlowTextView.

Comment: The image does not need to be a part of the text to show inline (as exemplified by FlowTextView). You could programmatically move the image location and trigger the FlowTextView to re-layout the text. To support different screen sizes you want the image to stick with a block of text (not a specific line or word that would not work well because words change position on different sized screen). You could archive this by separating each block of text into it's own FlowTextView thus you only have to specify the image location relative to the the block of text.